# Find element in List<> that contains two value

Tags: c#, list

I do have a problem to get a List item by using two values of my class.

Class:

```
class Movement
{
    public int movX;
    public int movY;

}
```

Code:

```
void checkMovement()
{
    List<Movement> lstMovement = new List<Movement>();
    Movement currentMovement = new Movement();
    currentMovement.movX = 1; currentMovement.movY = 1; lstMovement.Add(currentMovement);
    currentMovement.movX = 1; currentMovement.movY = 3; lstMovement.Add(currentMovement);
    currentMovement.movX = 1; currentMovement.movY = 4; lstMovement.Add(currentMovement);
    currentMovement.movX = 2; currentMovement.movY = 2; lstMovement.Add(currentMovement);
    currentMovement.movX = 2; currentMovement.movY = 4; lstMovement.Add(currentMovement);
    currentMovement.movX = 3; currentMovement.movY = 5; lstMovement.Add(currentMovement);
    Movement curMovement = lstMovement.Find(item => item.movX == 1 && item.movY == 3);
    Console.WriteLine(curMovement.movX + ", " + curMovement.movY);
}
```

If I am going to `Find` by one value, this works great.

Example for this one:

```
Movement curMovement = lstMovement.Find(item => item.movX == 3);
```

The Values are movX = 3 and movY = 5.

Can I find an list-object by using two expressions with this syntax?

Comment: That's not the issue. The issue is OP is reusing the same object and reference for every value in the list...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgott to use getters and setters so all properties was null. Code below works fine.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;                      

    public class Movement
    {
        public int movX {get; set;}
        public int movY {get; set;}    
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {

            List<Movement> lstMovement = new List<Movement>();     

            lstMovement.Add(new Movement() {movX = 1, movY = 3});
            lstMovement.Add(new Movement() {movX = 1, movY = 3});
            lstMovement.Add(new Movement() {movX = 2, movY = 2});
            lstMovement.Add(new Movement() {movX = 2, movY = 4});
            lstMovement.Add(new Movement() {movX = 3, movY = 5});       

            var curMovement = lstMovement.FirstOrDefault(item => item.movX == 1 && item.movY == 3);

            Console.WriteLine(curMovement.movX + ", " + curMovement.movY);      

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use &&

```
Movement curMovement = lstMovement.FirstOrDefault(item => item.movX == 3 && item.movY == 5);
```

Comment: If you want to have list of object fullfill condition:
`var curMovementList = lstMovement.Where(item => item.movX == 3 && item.MovY == 5).ToList();`

Comment: Yes, it depends on his specific requirements

Comment: This one returns null :/

Comment: Probably did not find any object, or error in `item.MovY == 5` change to `item.movY == 5`

Comment: nope... I did  `item.movX == 1 && item.movY == 3` which is right and  should be available...

Comment: Check the number of items in your list. Is there only one?

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing the very same object and adding it over and over again, as [commented by J. Steen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38608495/find-element-in-list-that-contains-two-value/38608627#comment64603759_38608495). To solve this, create a new instance every time:

```
lstMovement.Add(new Movement() { movX = 1, movY = 1 });
...
```

To get a list out, use `Where`:

```
IEnumerable<Movement> curMovements = lstMovement.Where(item => item.movX == 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using Where extension method like as:-

1. If you only interested in first item then:

   ```
   Movement curMovement = lstMovement.FirstOrDefault(item => item.movX == 1 && item.movY == 3);
   ```
2. If you interested in list then

   ```
   List<Movement> curMovement = lstMovement.Where(item => item.movX == 1 && item.movY == 3).ToList();
   ```